# How can I get given div id automatically at the time of scrolling document in angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I get ID of div element while scrolling the div up or down side in the document when I have multiple divs available in document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inView (https://www.npmjs.com/package/inview) to detect when your div is in the viewport and get its id.